# JAVA Имплементация коллекции AbstractSet

Tags: java, коллекции, set

На курсах начали изучать коллекции
Дали задание написать коллекцию, наследующую от AbstractSet, которая должна добавлять и удалять элементы в заданном диапазоне, я попробовал сделать на основе HashSet внутренний объект для хранения значений, но чувствую что вообще не понял что нужно делать, так как при выводе добавленных элементов получаю их номер, помогите разобраться как корректно добавлять хотя бы по одному элементу, как я понял нужно задействовать свой итератор

RangedOpsIntegerSet

```
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

class RangedOpsIntegerSet extends AbstractSet<Integer> {
    int current = 0;
    public RangedOpsIntegerSet() {

    }

    public boolean add(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean remove(int fromInclusive, int toExclusive) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(final Integer integer) {
        add(integer);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(final Object o) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator () {
      return new Iterator<Integer>() {
          public int index = 0;
           @Override
           public boolean hasNext() {
               return index < size();
           }

           @Override
           public Integer next() {
               return index++;
           }
       };
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.size();
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        RangedOpsIntegerSet ranged = new RangedOpsIntegerSet();

        ranged.add(10);
        ranged.add(23);
        ranged.add(3);
        for(Integer el : ranged)
            System.out.println(el);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитав документацию по классам `AbstractSet` и `AbstractCollection`, узнаём, что нужно реализовать/переопределить несколько методов:
`iterator()`, `size()`, `add(E e)`. Это обязательно.
Ну и если хотим, можно сделать свой `addAll`

```
public class MySet extends AbstractSet<Integer> {
    private final int min;
    private final int max;
    private final HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    public MySet(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return set.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return set.size();
    }

    // просто кидается исключениями, если число не проходит проверки
    private void checkAddArgument(Integer x) {
        if (x == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("null недопустим");
        if (x < min) throw new IllegalArgumentException("слишком мал");
        if (max < x) throw new IllegalArgumentException("слишком велик");
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Integer> collection) {
        for (Integer c : collection) checkAddArgument(c);
        return set.addAll(collection);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(Integer e) {
        checkAddArgument(e);
        return set.add(e);
    }
    
}
```

Чтобы попроще было, задействуем стандартный HashSet в качестве движка нашего множества. Весь необходимый функционал практически прямиком делегируются ему. Нужно только в `add` (и опционально в `addAll`) предварительно выполнить проверку аргументов, чтобы входили в заданный диапазон значений.
Если какое-либо из добавляемых чисел выходит за рамки, то вызывается исключение IllegalArgumentException.
Коллекция добавляется по правилу всё или ничего, поэтому сначала всё проверяется. Но можно упростить и вообще не переопределять `addAll`, полагаясь на стандартную реализацию(точного описания которой нет?).
Диапазон чисел, которые можно будет добавлять в этот Set указывается в конструкторе при создании MySet'a.

```
MySet mySet = new MySet(1, 10);
mySet.add(2);
mySet.add(8);
mySet.add(7);
mySet.add(7);
mySet.add(7); // будет добалена только одна 7, что будет заметно в выводе
mySet.add(10);
for(Integer el : mySet) {
    System.out.println(el);
}
mySet.add(35); // тут должно выскочить исключение
```

А итератором Вы ничего не добавите. Ни по-одному, ни кучей. Он немного для другого задуман:)

Comment: ох, теперь я хотя бы понял как это должно работать, спасибо большое!
я правильно понял, что итератор не только мы используем для прохода по значениям, но и метод add() работает с его помощью?

Comment: Нет не так. Метод `add` не работает с помощью итератора. Они оба работаю с третьей сущностью - непосредственным хранилищем объектов (которое надёжно скрыто в недрах стандартных коллекций:). Но между собой непосредственно вряд ли связаны. Могут только мешать друг другу.

Comment: ага, вроде понял) до этого для себя с++ учил, там всё как-то понятнее работало